# How does mysql optimizer works?

Tags: index, performance, optimization, index-tuning, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I have two tables t_core_blueprints,t_ci.

```
CREATE TABLE `t_core_blueprints` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

  `last_modified_on` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent_blueprint` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_ci_part` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_ci_part` (`is_ci_part`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `t_ci` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `record_id` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `last_modified_on` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blueprint_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `license_group` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s39` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK362C11874EFF37` (`blueprint_id`),
  KEY `record_id_index` (`record_id`(64)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `processed_remote_ci` (`archive`,`s39`,`blueprint_id`),
  KEY `lastModified` (`last_modified_on`),
  KEY `Test1` (`archive`,`last_modified_on`),
  KEY `Test2` (`blueprint_id`,`archive`,`last_modified_on`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK362C11874EFF37` FOREIGN KEY (`blueprint_id`) REFERENCES `t_core_blueprints` (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I am running two queries

---

```
SELECT tci0_.id AS col_0_0 
FROM t_ci tci0_ 
CROSS JOIN t_core_blueprints tmblueprin1_ 
WHERE tci0_.blueprint_id=tmblueprin1_.id 
  AND tmblueprin1_.is_ci_part=0 
  AND tci0_.archive=0;
```

EXPLAIN Plan for this query:-

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tci0_
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,AssetID,lastModified,Test1,Test2
          key: processed_remote_ci
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 889058
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tmblueprin1_
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,is_ci_part
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: emdb_1547105779479.tci0_.blueprint_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 65.71
        Extra: Using where
```

---

```
SELECT tci0_.id AS col_0_0 
FROM t_ci tci0_ 
CROSS JOIN t_core_blueprints tmblueprin1_ 
WHERE tci0_.blueprint_id=tmblueprin1_.id 
  AND tmblueprin1_.is_ci_part=0 
  AND tci0_.archive=0 
  AND tmblueprin1_.name LIKE '%%';
```

EXPLAIN Plan is:-

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tmblueprin1_
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,is_ci_part
          key: is_ci_part
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 69
     filtered: 11.11
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tci0_
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,AssetID,processed_remote_ci,lastModified,Test1,Test2
          key: Test2
      key_len: 7
          ref: emdb_1547105779479.tmblueprin1_.id,const
         rows: 93585
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

I am not able to understand just adding a condition **tmblueprin1_.name LIKE '%%'** in the second query made its execution faster. Can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: Do you really need the `DISTINCT`? It looks like you don't and removing it would likely improve performance.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  DISTINCT is needed for the requirement.

Comment: Why is it needed? You are selecting `tci0_.id` which is the primary key. Are you saying you get different results if you remove the `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I understood the mistake. I have edited the query . Thank you